# Is $ \mu (\{t:\lim_nf_n(t)\neq f(t) \text { or }\lim_n f_n (t) \text { does not exist }\})=0 $?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal {A} ,\mu)$ be a finite measure space and $\{f_n\} $ be a sequence of integrable function such that : for all $\epsilon \in]0,\frac {\sqrt{2}}{2}] $ 
$$
\lim_n\mu (\{t:\sup_{k\geq n}|f_k(t)-f(t)|>\epsilon\})=0
$$
Can we say that 
$$
\mu (\{t:\lim_nf_n(t)\neq f(t) \text { or }\lim_n f_n (t) \text { does not exist }\})=0
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $A_n:=\{t:\sup_{k\geq n}|f_k(t)-f(t)|>\epsilon\}$ and note that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu (A_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int \mathbf{1}_{A_n}\mathop{}\!d \mu\overset{(*)}{=}\int \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbf{1}_{A_n}\mathop{}\!d \mu =\mu (\{t:\limsup_{n\to\infty}|f_n(t)-f(t)|>\epsilon \})=0
$$
where in $(*)$ we used the monotone convergence theorem because $(A_n)$ is decreasing and $\mu$ is finite. Therefore $\mu (\{t:\limsup_{n\to\infty}|f_n(t)-f(t)|=0 \})=\mu(E)$, so $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct.  For each $m \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $N_m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mu(\{t : \sup_{k \ge N_m} |f_k(t)-f(t)| > \frac{1}{m}\}) < \frac{1}{2^m}$, so by the Borel-Cantelli lemma $$\mu(\{t : \sup_{k \ge N_m} |f_k(t)-f(t)| > \frac{1}{m} \text{ i.o.}\}) = 0.$$  If $t \not \in \{t : \sup_{k \ge N_m} |f_k(t)-f(t)| > \frac{1}{m} \text{ i.o.}\})$ then for all $m$ there exists an $N$ such that $|f_k(t)-f(t)| \le \frac{1}{m}$ for all $k \ge N$, which is the definition of $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_k(t)=f(t)$.